# AS3 Jump To Certain Word In Multiline Textfield?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I want to search a word in a textfiled which is multi line  , finding it is not a big deal but am i able to scroll to that position , like notepad when you click find next it will jump to that point

i am not asking to do it for me , could you give me a tip where should i look ?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT SOLUTION**

```
var textInput:String="String To Search";
txt.text=textInput; // txt is a dynamic textfield

var currentIndex:int = 0;

function search(searchInput) {

    var searchString:String = searchInput.toLowerCase();
    txt.stage.focus = txt;
    var txtForSearch:String = textInput.toLowerCase();

    if(currentIndex == 0){
        var index:int = txtForSearch.indexOf(searchString,currentIndex);
        currentIndex  = index+searchString.length;
    } else {
        index = txtForSearch.indexOf(searchString,currentIndex);
        currentIndex  = index+searchString.length;
    }
    if(index < 0) {
        txt.setSelection(0, 0);
    } else {
        txt.setSelection(index, currentIndex);
    }
}

input.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, inputChanged);
function inputChanged (e:TextEvent):void {
    currentIndex = 0;
}

srBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,doSearch) // srBtn my search button instance
function doSearch(e:Event):void{
    search(input.text); // input is an input textfield ( search query )     
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set [`TextField.scrollV`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#scrollV) according to [`TextField.getCharBoundaries()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getCharBoundaries%28%29)

Comment: `TextField.getCharBoundaries()` return certain index in visible part of texfield , i mean if text is too long `getCharBoundaries()` return null  if given index is not shown in visible part of textfield ! is there any work around it ?

Comment: maybe `while(!tf.getCharBoundaries(1111)){tf.scrollV++;}`

Comment: i did it with setSelection , anyway thankyou , your suggestion lead me into nice posts over forums

Answer (score 1):

I wrestled with this problem for several hours.  I was getting a null rectangle and I fiunally figured out that the textfield original size was smaller than the expanded size after it autosized to fit more text.

everything outside of the original textField size returned a null.  I solved the problem by expanding the size of the textField on the stage so that it was big enough to fit all the dynamic text.

I usually dont use timeline animations but it was a client provided file.

thanks to this loop that helped me figure out what was going on:

```
for(var i:int= 0; i<tf.text.length; i++)
{
var char:String = tf.text.substr(i,1);
trace(i, ": " , (char=="\n"||char=="\r" ?"<CR>":char) ,": ",  tf.getCharBoundaries(i))
}
```